# How to use loop to create new data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 300 locations, let's say "A1, A2, A3,..., A300" and I have 40 values. My Locations are in df1 and my values are in df2. I want to add those 40 values to each location, location A1 would have codes from  to 40 and so on.

I tried to make a for loop:

```
df1 <- c("A1", "A2", "A3")
df1 <- data.frame(df1)
colnames(df1) <- c("location")

df2 <- c(1:40)
df2 <-data.frame(df2)
colnames(df2) <- c("code")

data <- data.frame() #Empty data.frame

for (i in df2) {
  temp <- df1
  temp$code <- rep(i)
  data1 <- rbind(data, temp)
}
```

This script results in an Error:  'replacement has 40 rows, data has 315'.

Can someone tell me what should I do to make this work?

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Your description is not clear.  Could you show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: The line `temp$value <- rep(i)` looks wrong in the loop. `rep(i)` without the "times" argument essentially made it equivalent to `print(i)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Value ~Location, df1, sum)
```

---

If the values are in a different dataset and have the same order as in the original dataset 'Location', just do a `cbind` and `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Value ~Location, cbind(df1, df2), sum)
```

Assuming that there are no common columns in each dataset to `merge`

#### Update

Based on the OP's update

```
expand.grid(location = df1$location, code = df2$code)
```

Or `CJ` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(location = df1$location, code = df2$code)
```